# Nette - database INSERT - number of affected rows

Tags: nette

I would like to find out the number of affected (inserted) rows after inserting into the table. I didn't figure out how to do it in the documentation. The update returns the number of affected rows. The insert returns `Nette\Database\Table\ActiveRow`
How do I get it?

```
$affected = $context->table('author')->insert([
    [
        'name' => 'Sansa Stark',
        'born' => null
    ], [
        'name' => 'Arya Stark',
        'born' => null
    ]
]);
bdump($affected); //  Nette\Database\Table\ActiveRow - I need the number of inserted records
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nette Database Explorer doesn't return count after `insert()`. It is not useful information as long as you can count data before insert by yourself.

```php
$data = [...];
$count = count($data);
$context->table('author')->insert($data);
```

It works only with `update` and `delete` as is mentioned in [documentation](https://doc.nette.org/en/3.0/database-explorer#toc-insert-update-delete).

```php
$count = $context->table('author')
    ->where('id', 10)
    ->delete();
```

---

It might be possible with `getRowCount()` over `query` in [Nette Database Core](https://doc.nette.org/en/3.0/database-core)

Comment: Thank you for your help. It could be done as you write:
`$affected = $this->database->query('INSERT INTO invoices (name, born) VALUES ('Sansa Stark', ''), ('Arya Stark', '');  bdump($affected->getRowCount()); // return 2`

Answer (score 0):

Nette Database Core is built upon PDO. Alas, the authors tend to create their own objects instead of extending PDO, which makes such elementary operations tedious:

```
// get Nette ResultSet object
$resultSet = $this->database->query("INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE...");

// get original PDOStatement object
$pdoStatement = $resultSet->getPdoStatement();

// get the affected rows from PDO object (instead of $resultSet->rowCount())
$pdoStatement->rowCount();
```

A word of warning for those considering Nette for production: There is no real documentation, only [cook books](https://doc.nette.org/en/database/explorer#toc-insert-update-delete) and [autogenerated PHPDoc](https://api.nette.org/database/master/Nette/Database/ResultSet.html) which just prints names without any explanation.